# noclassdeffounderror on device

Tags: java, android, devise, try-catch

I have same code:

```
public static void clearCacheWithoutMainActivity()
{
    try
    {
        viewModelForClass.entrySet().removeIf(e -> !e.getKey().equals(className));
    }
    catch(NoClassDefFoundError e)
    {
        int k = 0;
    }
}

private static Map<String, Pair<BaseObservable, Date>> viewModelForClass = new LinkedHashMap<>();

private static final String className = MainActivity.class.getName();
```

In emulator android i don't catch error NoClassDefFoundError. But in my device this android 5.1 i catch this error.

```
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

  defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ca.amikash.cashback"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        jumboMode = false
        maxProcessCount 4
        javaMaxHeapSize "6g"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

My build.gradle file. That can be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It would be more helpful you could share the error logs too.

Have you edited your manifest file to set android:name in the  tag as follows:

```
<application android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
```

Or if you override the Application class, change it to extend **MultiDexApplication**

Check out this link for more info: [developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ca.amikash.cashback.ViewModelProvider$$Lambda$1 just this error. extend MultiDexApplication - did not help me

Comment: Are you using a library project which has a class ca.amikash.cashback.ViewModelProvider ?

Comment: In class TheApplication extends MultiDexApplication i use ViewModelProvider.clearCacheWithoutMainActivity();

Comment: If you haven't yet, can you try to clean rebuild your project and then run the app again?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42946372/3274299 - Do not know what it could be connected with?

Comment: If you are using retrolambda, this issue maybe related to it. Check this out https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda/issues/37. Many people reported clean building the project has solved similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Pair<BaseObservable, Date>>> it = viewModelForClass.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            Map.Entry<String, Pair<BaseObservable, Date>> entry = it.next();
            if(!entry.getKey().equals(className)) {
                it.remove();
            }
        }
```

Instead

```
   viewModelForClass.entrySet().removeIf(e -> !e.getKey().equals(className));
```

Solved the problem. But still did not understand why the exclusion was thrown out. And the code without lambdas is not beautiful, but what to do.